# personalize this page - DB location

Tags: content-database, personalization

I am currently using the "personalize this page" feature for a web part page. I've had users make changes to their personal page although I can't locate this information in the content database.

Ultimately my question is where is this information being stored?

Answer (score 0):

In your content database there is a table called "Personalization", where all these changes are stored. One entry for each webpart/user/page. Since this is a feature provided by ASP.NET's Web Parts personlization service this only applies to Web Part pages in SharePoint.

Comment: A description of the Columns in the table can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585188%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: That's what I initially thought too but I just checked and my Personalization table is completely empty even thought I have about two users with different personal view for some site pages.

Comment: If I make an edit to an already existing web part a row is added to the table. Although if I simply add a new web part to my personalized page nothing is added to the table.